# Safari issue with video in jQuery accordion (not ui)

Tags: jquery, video, safari, accordion

Hey there forum members.
I have got a known issue with en embeded (via object-tag) video in an jQuery-tab-accordion which I developped myself (no jQuery-ui).
Since the issue doesn't depend on my code because I use jQueries *slideUp()* and *slideDown()*, I do without posting code for now.

When I slide down or up a panel the video shown in one of the panels disappears time-delayed.
In other words, as soon as you click the respective tab to slide the panel with the vid down it appears and you can see it slide up and vice versa. #*edit*# I mean outside the panel #*endedit*#

I martyred my favoured search engine for quite a while with no result.
Someone gave the hint to use the youTube API to get around with this issue but I can't really see how this would help.

Does anyone know how to work around this annoying problem ?

All other browsers (even IE9 ;-)) show everything perfectly right (webkit (except Safari), gecko, presto).

Cheers,
noRiddle

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested:
Solved the problem by using valid XHTML to embed the video,
which on its own, however, didn't help.
What did help though was to add wmode transparent and
Eureka, the issue is gone.

Just to know why I said its a known issue:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/safari-issue-with-embedded-video-in-accordion

noRiddle